# probability of tossing head

Tags: conditional-probability

$A$ and $B$ are playing a coin tossing game. $A$ starts the game and if he gets a head the game is over and he wins $\$100$ cash. If he gets a tail $B$ will toss the coin and if he gets a head the game is over and $B$ will get $\$100$ cash. The game continuous until one gets a head. Find the probabilities that $B$ will get $\$100$ cash and the probability that $A$ will win $\$100$ cash.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability that A (ultimately) wins. We condition on the result of the first toss. If it is head, then A wins. If it is a tail, the roles are reversed, and the probability A ultimately wins is $1-p$. Thus
$$p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-p).$$

**Remark:** Alternately, by tracing the conditions under which A wins, namely H, HTH, HTTTH, and so on, we find that the probability A wins is
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots\right).$$
Sum the infinite geometric series.

Comment: is it for both?

Comment: Solving for $p$ we get $2/3$. Thus the probability B wins is $1/3$. One can also calculate using an infinite series.

Comment: ı get it thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. The same methods work also with a biased coin. Conditioning on the first result is a useful tool, both for probabilities and for expectations.